# Is there an easy way of summarizing the relationship between Samba access/permissions and linux file system permissions?

Tags: samba, file-permissions

Configuring a Samba share can be a challenge if you’re not a professional admin. A hobbyist or home user will set up a Samba server once and probably not touch it in years thereafter - if they even manage to figure out the permissions at all, that is. Many will probably just try to remove any restrictions wherever they can, just to get back to “real life,” but it’s obviously better to not use your `777` permissions too extensively.

So the aim of this question is to elicit some basic advice regarding two interrelated challenges that one encounters when configuring a Samba server:

1. Given that (non-admin) users don't have access to the files other than via Samba, is it sufficient (from a security perspective) to set all files to `777` (or perhaps `770`) and differentiate access via access to Samba permissions only?
2. Once you've set permissions to existing files and folders correctly, you need to figure out how to make sure that new files written by Samba users will have the correct permissions. The relevant Samba settings for this seem to be `force group` and `force user` (right?). So my intuition is to set these so that all files written by users on a particular share will have the same ownership as all the other files. But when I look at various Samba configurations posted on the web, it seems that those parameters are actually rarely used. So my reasoning seems to be somewhat unusual and I wonder how to make sure that files will be accessible by all users with access to a particular share *without* using `force group` and `force user`?

**Edit in response to comments:**

Yes, this is not the typical here-is-my-problem-how-do-I-fix-it question. Much can be (and has been) said about the topics touched upon above. So much, that the point of this question is precisely to find an as-easy-as-possible way of summarizing.

What I wrote above is meant to help people understand the the question (not the least because those who have a good answer may not even understand why it is a question, as it is so obvious to them). If you don’t find it helpful, ignore the post and focus on the question (which is in the title).

Comment: You touch enough topics that you could likely fill a book with this. It sounds like you want to write a really long blog post. In addition you mention that you already learned a lot but don't really mention what you learned. It's unclear if you're look for the right format or actual input on what to do. Did you try one of the formats? Did you build anything based on the information you already got?

Comment: This ins't a question. Every system should be designed and set up, in order to be implemented. That is, how it will deliver. Permissions should be granted to users and groups, as they need to. Again, to deliver the service you designed previously. When a project have some time on the run, it will change as needs in time changed, so it's time for a new iteration. You can start something new from the ground up, or recycle what you already got.

Answer (score 1):

You state the following:

> “So, the main aim of this question is to provide anything that will help admins to reduce some of this complexity.”

While you might be well intentioned, the thing is when you as something like this you are assuming tons of things. I have worked as a sysadmin in multiple places with multiple requirements and multiple systems interacting and there is no way to simplify this.

Every sysadmin has a “bag of tricks” and piles of notes they carry from gig to gig that help make their life easier in some ways. But at the end of the day systems are made, architected and designed for people to use. And each group of people will have different requirements, limits and resources.

Again, your question is very well intentioned and idealistic, but it’s not at all realistic to how systems are implemented in the real world.